# Horizontal Layout: div ignores width of child div

Tags: html, layout, size, alignment

I am currently trying to create a column-based, scrollable, horizontal layout. After playing around with `float: left` and `position: absolute`, but discovering that they do not behave the way I want them to, I am now back to very straightforward HTML - but unfortunately, my code is still not behaving as expected.

I currently use the following HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<div style="height: 600px; width: 1320px;">
    <div class="newsify_column" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; margin-right: 20px;">some text can be put here, but it is made sure that this column is never higher than 600px!</div>
    <div class="newsify_column" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; margin-right: 20px;">some text can be put here, but it is made sure that this column is never higher than 600px!</div>
    <div class="newsify_column" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; margin-right: 20px;">some text can be put here, but it is made sure that this column is never higher than 600px!</div>
    <div class="newsify_column" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; margin-right: 20px;">some text can be put here, but it is made sure that this column is never higher than 600px!</div>
    <div class="newsify_column" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; margin-right: 20px;">some text can be put here, but it is made sure that this column is never higher than 600px!</div>
    <div class="newsify_column" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; margin-right: 0px;">some text can be put here, but it is made sure that this column is never higher than 600px!</div>
</div>
</div>
```

([JSFiddle of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/M9q3h/))

Basically it is working, the problem I am having is that the `content`-div is ignoring the size of its child div and in turn the body tag does not have the correct size as well! The `content`-div is having the correct height, but its width is the width of the browser window - not 1320px. This is bad because it means other elements on the page that I want to have a width of 100% are incorrectly sized and I cannot use margins or paddings on the `content`-div.

I don't really understand what is going on here - I don't use any floats or absolute elements and have an element that is explicitly sized. Why is the `content`-div ignoring this? Shouldn't it have the necessary size to contain its children? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use inline-block for content div as well.

A display:block element automatically gets 100% width by default.
So body have 100% width (size of viewport, i.e browser window size)
and in turn its child content also has 100% width.

Comment: that works great, thank you! but this would mean that in order to have other elements on the page with the same width as the content, I would have to make the `body`-tag `inline-block` as well... I suppose this is considered bad practice? Are there any other solutions to this?

Comment: @BlackWolf, is it possible to make those elements children of content?

Comment: the columns are created dynamically using JS, but I think I can adjust the JS if it helps solve this issue.